# Background image not scaling in mobile browsers

Tags: html, css

I've tried so many things... I can't get the site to scale to a mobile browser.

```
body{
  background: url("Photo-Carpentry-Tools-Wood-Planks-Collage-21.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Additionally I've tried

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable = yes">
```

and a few other variations of above code.

The site is actually live now - it's www.readyshift.net - works fine in Chrome, doesn't work in mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I've taken a look at your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufnx7gnq/) and noticed that you used `background-size:100%` in it on the `html, body` selector, after seeing this I visited your [live website](http://www.readyshift.net/) and saw that you used it there as well.

If you change the `background-size:100%` in the `html, body` selector, the background image scales to mobile sites properly (tested on your [live website](http://www.readyshift.net/) by changing the value through developer console).

TL:DR you want to change the `html, body` to:

```
html,body { 
    background: url("http://www.readyshift.net/css/Photo-Carpentry-Tools-Wood-Planks-Collage-21.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scaleable="yes">`? But since he wants users to be able to zoom, you can just write `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1>` since user-scalable is standard on "yes". Here is a useful [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) if you want more information.

Comment: @ZiggyVerstrepen - You're right, I must've forgotten the ',' or something, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @ZiggyVerstrepen i tried that, and it still didn't work. When I do that, my nav bar gets all jumbled, and the picture takes up more of the page, but still not the whole thing.

Comment: @Josh - Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) so I can play around with your code a bit to find the solution?

Comment: @Josh - did you copy the code in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufnx7gnq/) directly from your source?

Comment: @Josh I've visited the live website and noticed you use `background-size: 100%` there, see my answer for the explanation as to what to change